# I want to know , Is there a more efficient way to do this

Tags: java, jpa, java-stream

There is a method which is saveCountryIslands which takes a String array argument. There is an Entity which is Country and the Islands.

I had been trying to save the provided list of island titles using 
jpa `.save()`.

The existing method body is already working (you can see the code below).

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

```java
private void saveCountryIslands(String[] islandNames){

    List<Islands> listOfIsland = new ArrayList<>();
    Country country=new Country();

    Stream.of(islandNames).distinct().forEach(islandNamesFromArray -> {
      Islands islands = new Islands();
      islands.setIslandName(islandNamesFromArray);
      listOfIsland.add(islands);
    });

    country.setCountryIslands(listOfIsland);
    countryRepository.save(country);

}
```

Comment: With some indentation, it is all the same clearer.

Comment: In terms of   `countryRepository.save()` invocation, it is efficient : you do that once.  
I suppose that you used the cascade save option. So it is nice.

Comment: You should check the size of *listOfIsland* before saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small change that you can bring in the readability is by using a constructor as:

```
    public Islands(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

and then refactoring the existing code as :

```
    List<Islands> listOfIsland = Stream.of(islandNames)
            .distinct()
            .map(Islands::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect 'toSet' depending on compatibility
```

Comment: For an existing array, I’d use `Arrays.stream` rather than `Stream.of`.

Comment: @Naman Sorry for  late replay from my side Dear , this is the closest answer  ,Thank you , when I got your answer , I have given you up vote , now I'm going to accept it , many thank Dear